# Adding new flags to custom Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, c++

Recently, I've been trying to add a new flag to a custom Linux kernel that'll be used by `mmap` for educational purposes. I've successfully compiled and installed the kernel with this addition but the flag does not appear to be visible when I try to `make` a test program with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 1000000000
 
int main()
{
    long* arr = (long*)mmap(
        NULL,
        ARR_SIZE * sizeof(long),
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_COLOR2, /*ERROR: 'MAP_COLOR2' was not declared in this scope*/
        -1,
        0
     );
 
     if (arr == MAP_FAILED) {
         std::cout << "Failed to mmap..." << std::endl;
     } else {
         for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; ++i) {
             arr[i] = 1;
         }
     }
 
     return 0;
}
```

That's when I noticed some of the header files in `usr/include/linux` did not have the changes I made so I:

1. ran `make headers_install` in the top of the source directory of my custom kernel (no change)
2. Followed these [instructions](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.0/chapter05/linux-headers.html) which successfully updated the header files in `usr/include/linux` but still lead to the same error.

Then I found that `sys/mman.h` lived under `usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` and seemed to get it's macro/flag definitions from files under `usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/` (which did not contain my flag). Instead of adding my flag manually to these files, what is the proper way to make my changes to the kernel visible here as well? What's the relationship between files under `usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `usr/include/linux`?

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the flag was not showing up because the header is for the Glibc wrapper of `mmap` and not the Linux kernel syscall. The more you learn!